# How to trigger on blur in jQuery with exception of clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an input field wrapped within a jQuery mobile 1.4.5 environment which will scroll up on focus to provide space on mobile for search suggestions.

[image]

Upon filling out the field, it will scroll back down.

```
$('#refn').on('blur',function(){

  if ( (document.querySelector('.ui-input-clear-hidden') !== null) ) {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 200);
  }

  return false;
});
```

JQM will provide a clear link on the right, which will clear the text field. This is a problem, as clicking it will defocus and trigger the scroll down function. Resulting in a scroll down and up again effect.

I tried to exclude it by recognizing the class `.ui-input-clear-hidden` but this has no effect. I believe because it is a link that takes away focus from the field.

```
<a href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" 
class="
 ui-input-clear 
 ui-btn 
 ui-icon-delete 
 ui-btn-icon-notext 
 ui-corner-all" 
title="Clear text">Clear text</a>
```

I want to trigger the function only if the clear button is not clicked. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand, the issue is when you click on the clear text button, it execute your button that scroll down ?

I think you can try to get the focused element and if it's the clear button you do nothing

```
$('#refn').on('blur',function(){

  var focused_element = document.querySelector(':focus') ; //Get the focused element.
  if ( focused_element.hasClass('.ui-input-clear-hidden') ) {
    //It's the clear button
     return false;
  }else{
     //It's not your clear button
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 200);
  }
});
```

Edit :: try to store your clear_btn click in a var

```
//Function to force wait time
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

var clear_btn_clicked = false;

//Event on click
$(document).on("click",function(){
     //You clicked on the X btn
     if( $(this).hasClass('ui-input-clear-hidden' ) ){
         clear_btn_cliked = true;
     }else{
         clear_btn_clicked = false;
     }
});


$('#refn').on('blur',function(){
  await timeout(500); //Wait 0.5s to let JS do the clear_btn click event
  if( clear_btn_clicked === false ){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 200); //You didn't click on the X
  }else{
    return false; //You clicked on the X
  }
});

//You do same for your focus function
 $('#refn').on('focus',function(){
     await timeout(500); //Wait 0.5s to let JS do the clear_btn click event
     if( clear_btn_clicked === false ){
          //Scroll up
     }else{
          //Don't go up
     }
 });
```

Comment: Interesting approach. While trying to implement I do get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of null". Are you sure that this works? (jq 2.1.4)

Comment: Could you try with -> var focused_element = $(':focus') ; <- instead of " var focused_element = document.querySelector(':focus') ; "

That's because document.querySelector returns HTML and $() return a JQuery object with function like 'HasClass'

Comment: Not sure if this is the right approach, even  if ( $('.ui-input-clear').is(':focus') ) will not work as the focus is "undefined".

Comment: Why don't you put your Scroll up animation on an input focus event ? It may be easier i think

Comment: This is the case. $('#refn').on('focus')... The mentioned function is the on blur, which unfortunatelly also happens if the X is clicked. After that it will gain focus again a second later. So it will go down and up again

Comment: What about bind an event on a click on X , you store in a var (clear_btn_clicked) that you click and in your blur function you check if the var clear_btn_clicked is true or false